# Python Pandas: How to create randomized timestamps at minute level between two fixed dates

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, timestamp

I would like to create 100 randomized timestamps at minute level between two fixed dates (2018-06-01 to 2018-06-11) and fill those into a dataframe. The final dataframe would look like this (this is just a demo):

```
+-----+---------------------+
|     | timestamp           |
+-----+---------------------+
| 0   | 2018-06-01 04:26:00 |
+-----+---------------------+
| 1   | 2018-06-01 05:55:00 |
+-----+---------------------+
| 2   | 2018-06-01 06:11:00 |
+-----+---------------------+
| 3   | 2018-06-01 07:56:00 |
+-----+---------------------+
|     | ...                 |
+-----+---------------------+
|     | ...                 |
+-----+---------------------+
|     | ...                 |
+-----+---------------------+
| 97  | 2018-06-11 19:28:00 |
+-----+---------------------+
| 98  | 2018-06-11 20:47:00 |
+-----+---------------------+
| 99  | 2018-06-11 21:47:00 |
+-----+---------------------+
| 100 | 2018-06-11 22:54:00 |
+-----+---------------------+
| 101 | 2018-06-11 23:20:00 |
+-----+---------------------+
```

I know how to create all the minutes between the two dates by doing `pd.date_range(start="2018-06-01 00:00:00",end="2018-06-12 00:00:00", freq="T")`, but not sure how exactly can I randomly pick 100 timestamps(and then fill those back into a dataframe).

Much appreciation for your help!

Answer (score 1):

[numpy.random.choice](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) can be used

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = pd.date_range(start="2018-06-01 00:00:00",end="2018-06-12 00:00:00", freq="T")
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(d, 100), columns=['timestamp'])
```

output

```
timestamp
0   2018-06-08 20:20:00
1   2018-06-11 22:15:00
2   2018-06-10 19:25:00
3   2018-06-05 04:49:00
4   2018-06-06 08:06:00
... ...
95  2018-06-06 06:51:00
96  2018-06-03 00:50:00
97  2018-06-03 10:06:00
98  2018-06-01 08:12:00
99  2018-06-05 23:39:00
```